# What does the complexity equation constitute exactly in “Why Should I Trust You?” LIME paper

Tags: machine-learning, papers, notation, explainable-ai

I've recently been reading [this paper on LIME](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1602.04938.pdf), an algorithm to interpret ANY machine learning model. I encountered this equation (in red) on page 4 and have just been having a hard time deciphering exactly what it means. I understand that it's a measure of complexity of something - but of what exactly? And what does each symbol in the equation entail and correspond to? What part(s) of the models and instances constitute and contribute to the complexity?

> For text classification, we ensure that the explanation is interpretable by letting the *interpretable representation* be a bag of words, and by setting a limit $K$ on the number of words, i.e. $\color{red}{\Omega(g)=\infty \mathbb{1}\left[\left\|w_{g}\right\|_{0}>K\right]}$. Potentially, $K$ can be adapted to be as big as the user can handle, or we could have different values of $K$ for different instances.

Could anyone help me with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's brake down each component of the formula, on the left side we have

${\Omega(g)}$

The authors state that they use omega to refer to the set of models too difficult to be tractable (or explained), so *g* is just a model, or set of weights, omega g is a set of models. Next we have

${\infty \mathbb{1}}$

This is not a common notation, at least as far as I'm aware of, but conceptually they're trying to say there an infinite amount of such models, 1 could refer to the cardinality of the set, but honestly not 100% sure about it. Finally we have:

${\left[\left\|w_{g}\right\|_{0}>K\right]}$

This is the constrain that separate the intractable  models from the tractable ones. K refers to the number of words allowed in the bag-of-words model used to convert words into numbers. If you're not familiar with that, you can simply think of it as one hot encoding. So if you have a vocabulary of 30k words, every word vector will be a one dimensional vector of length 30k, with a single 1 and all rest zeros. That zero norm might looks weird, but it simply refers to the length of the vectors. So to summarize:

${\Omega(g)=\infty \mathbb{1}\left[\left\|w_{g}\right\|_{0}>K\right]}$

Means: "The infinite set of intractable models, made of weights vectors with length larger than a predefined value K".

PS: if you're interested in models interpretability, you might want to check [Integrated Gradients](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1703.01365.pdf), the authors created a fantastic [repo](https://captum.ai/) that implement many algorithms for pytorch.